# VBA code to save Excel sheet as tab-delimited text file

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code and tried it. It works fine, but in the saved text file the first column has blank space (for all rows). I am unable to fix this code.

```
Sub ExportRange()
Dim ExpRng As Range
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AllDXL.txt" For Output As #1
Set ExpRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
FirstCol = ExpRng.Columns(1).Column
LastCol = FirstCol + ExpRng.Columns.Count - 1
FirstRow = ExpRng.Rows(1).Row
LastRow = FirstRow + ExpRng.Rows.Count - 1
For r = FirstRow To LastRow
 Data = ""
 For c = FirstCol To LastCol
  '  data = ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
  Data = Data & vbTab & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
Next c
Print #1, Data
Next r
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this might save someone some time:

```vb
Sub ExportToTxt()
    Dim fileStream As Object
    Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    fileStream.Charset = "utf-8"
    fileStream.Open
    
    ' set the range you'd like to export
    Dim rangeToExport As Range
    Set rangeToExport = Worksheets("BPC-Processed").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim firstCol, lastCol, firstRow, lastRow As Integer
    firstCol = rangeToExport.Columns(1).Column
    lastCol = firstCol + rangeToExport.Columns.Count - 1
    firstRow = rangeToExport.Rows(1).row
    lastRow = firstRow + rangeToExport.Rows.Count - 1
    
    ' iterate the range, write text to stream
    Dim r, c As Integer
    Dim str, delimiter As String
    For r = firstRow To lastRow
        str = ""
        For c = firstCol To lastCol
            If c = 1 Then
                delimiter = ""
            Else
                delimiter = vbTab ' tab
            End If
            str = str & delimiter & rangeToExport.Cells(r, c).Value
        Next c
        fileStream.WriteText str & vbCrLf ' vbCrLf: linebreak
    Next r
    
    ' flush stream
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\BPC-Processed.txt"
    fileStream.SaveToFile filePath, 2 ' 2: Create Or Update
    fileStream.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Also this works ...

```
Sub ExportRange()
Dim ExpRng As Range
Dim myTab As String
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AllDXL.txt" For Output As #1
    Set ExpRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    FirstCol = ExpRng.Columns(1).Column
    LastCol = FirstCol + ExpRng.Columns.Count - 1
    FirstRow = ExpRng.Rows(1).Row
    LastRow = FirstRow + ExpRng.Rows.Count - 1
    For r = FirstRow To LastRow
       Data = ""
       For c = FirstCol To LastCol
           If c = 1 Then myTab = "" Else myTab = vbTab
        '  data = ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
           Data = Data & myTab & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
       Next c
       Print #1, Data
   Next r
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're prefixing with a `vbTab` for each cell, including the first. Change the following:

```
Data = Data & vbTab & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
```

to

```
If c = FirstCol Then
    Data = Data & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
Else
    Data = Data & vbTab & ExpRng.Cells(r, c).Value
End If
```

Alternatively, if there will always be some data on each line, you could just strip the first `vbTab` from each line during the `Print` stage by:

Changing

```
Print #1, Data
```

to

```
Print #1, Mid(Data, 2, Len(Data)-1)
```

Comment: Thanks CLR, the  **Print #1, Mid(Data, 2, Len(Data)-1)** caused to omit first character in the first column data. 

I changed it to **Print #1, Mid(Data, 1, Len(Data)-1)** it worked. Thanks

Comment: You aren't using *both* of my answers are you? You only need one or the other. If you use the first (with the `IF ELSE THEN` structure) then you don't need the `Print` change. If you use both but change the `Print` part to  `Print #1, Mid(Data, 1, Len(Data)-1)` you will LOSE the LAST character on each line.

Comment: Great, Thanks CLR